# Is there a way to "blank" or unplot a Google chart point?

Tags: google-visualization

I am plotting an oscilloscope type of chart, showing microphone pitch, for example:
[image: Example plot]

There are times when the mic input level is too low to be able to measure pitch accurately. I detect this and have a flag *isSquelched*.

Is there a way to prevent the G charts from plotting the point(s)  e.g. to flag the data array in some way?

Comment: try replacing the value with null, or you might try using the [certainty column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#certaintyrole) to indicate these data points are uncertain...

Comment: Thanks - null worked just fine